# Xilinx Virtext 5 microblaze digilent communicate with Pmodacl or pmodjstck

Tags: fpga, microblaze

I have a project that I need to control my Irobot creative using microblaze and Pmodacl or Pmodjstck from digilent.

I already set up my peripheral to be SPI interface (I also understand SPI working); however, I dont know how to communicate with the pmodacl?

I have searched all over the net and I dont see any example how to do it. I would be a great help if you give me some example.

Comment: Have you tried the examples from Digilent: http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=PMOD-ACL

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am very new to FPGA. Because the file run on MPIDE, I dont know how to use it. Also I dont know how to port the library file into SDK.

Comment: I saw some document and I will try it. Also i dont know what is MPIDE, and it seems like our school does not have the program.

Comment: The demo is using MPIDE, I am using microblaze EDK environment. So it will not work that way. Right now I cannot communicate between the board and the device.